# PHP: Zip a file stream on the fly on an intermediate server, without storing (too much) data

Tags: php, stream, zip, proc-open

Related:

- [On-the-fly zipping & streaming of large files, in PHP or otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357073/on-the-fly-zipping-streaming-of-large-files-in-php-or-otherwise)
- [Streaming a large file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914912/streaming-a-large-file-using-php)

I'm looking for a combination of methods described in the other topics. I probably need to read the file (from URL) **in small chunks**, pipe these into the STDIN of a proc_open zip command, grab output and flush this towards the client.

What I need to do:

- Read a file stream from an URL from a storage server
- Zip it on the fly on a webserver
- Offer it as a download to the web browser, using content-disposition with unknown size (it's a stream after all).

What I can't do:

- Store files on the webserver
- Run code on the storage server
- Use a lot of memory
- Let the client wait for the download

So the flushing of data needs to start while remote chunk-reading is still in progress.

Would this be possible in PHP? I feel like this would be much easier in languages which offer more callback/async functionality, but I'm stuck with PHP in this situation.

Any examples or some rough code would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It's not PHP, but this project does exactly what you're looking for. You can host it as a standalone server and call it from php:

https://github.com/scosman/zipstreamer