# PHP on the fly flush xml to zipfile and push download

Tags: php, xml, zip, flush, on-the-fly

I create a xml file based on information from my database (xmltv format). These xml files can be quite big - 25-70mb is normal. Now i create the xml file on the fly like this:

```
$xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
$xmlWriter->openURI('php://output');
```

and flush through the loop to prevent memory overflow. I also set headers to push the content as download:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $config->filename . '.xml"');
```

I would like to be able to zip/gzip the xml because of the size. Is this possible on the fly? I have used PHPZip before, which works good with files, but i dont know if i can write the xml output directly to the zip?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699777/php-zip-a-file-stream-on-the-fly-on-an-intermediate-server-without-storing-to?rq=1 as one possibility

Comment: Thanks but not what im looking for, also the awnser there does create a zipfile but doesnt compress the zip. Which i do need..

Comment: A zipfile is, by definition, compressed.

Comment: Thats not entirely true.. Zip is a container, so it package files.. It canbe compressed but there are also zip files which are not compressed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, the goal is to create gzip compressed data dynamically, without creating a file on the server. This is possible with [`deflate_init`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.deflate-init.php) and [`deflate_add`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.deflate-add.php), but requires PHP 7.

```
$gzip = deflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP, array('level' => 9));
$data = deflate_add($gzip, "my", ZLIB_NO_FLUSH);
$data .= deflate_add($gzip, "data", ZLIB_FINISH);
```

With `deflate_add` we can add more data any number of times (the mode should be `ZLIB_FINISH` for the last chunk).

We can adjust this method using [`XMLWriter::openMemory`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-open-memory.php) (stores the data in memory) and [`XMLWriter::flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-flush.php), to zip the xml elements as they are produced, and create the contents of a .gz file on the fly. For example this code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.gz"');

$xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
$xmlWriter->openMemory();
$xmlWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$gzip = deflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP, array('level' => 9));

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $xmlWriter->writeElement("element", $i);
    $data = $xmlWriter->outputMemory();
    echo deflate_add($gzip, $data, ZLIB_NO_FLUSH);
}
echo deflate_add($gzip, "", ZLIB_FINISH);
```

creates xml elements, compresses and outputs them one by one, without using too much memory or any files.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what i need! Perfect! I am using it in a almost same way now, where i create xmlwriter like: `xmlWriter->openURI('php://output');` where i flush everytime i write an element.