# download multiple files as zip in php without save on host

Tags: php, zip

I use this way for download multiple files as zip :

```
$files = array('readme.txt', 'test.html', 'image.gif');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

**But the file `file.zip` be save on my host . I don't want to save on my host i just wanna download it withou save .**

Thank

Comment: if you don't save it, then where are you going to download it from? you can run another script to clean it up with [unlink()](http://php.net/unlink)

Comment: You may find [this useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357073/on-the-fly-zipping-streaming-of-large-files-in-php-or-otherwise/4357904#4357904)

Comment: @JonathanYanivBenAvraham Thank you but it can't help me

Comment: @mistermartin but if more than one user wanna to download a file at a momment make a promlem becouse many of my files have similar name

Comment: Firstly are you using any frameworks for this project? I.e Symfony2, Laravel, Zend, CakePHP, CodeIgniter?

Comment: Dear @JonathanYanivBenAvraham no i don't use

Comment: @Amin Okay, so I'm not entirely sure what you want this to do, do you want to create the file in your code and download it? like you would with xml or csv? Without saving it to the server?

Comment: @JonathanYanivBenAvraham I don't use XML or CSV .I just combination many files in one ZIP file and next send for user for download with class.httpdownload .But i wanna do it without save on my host because in future make many problem for me .

Comment: @Amin do you mean saving it on your server in a local directory, so it's only downloaded on the client computer?

Comment: @JonathanYanivBenAvraham Yes right .

Comment: You don't need to save it onto the server, just send it out in the headers. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1754359/5971639) Where on your local directory is the file being saved?

Comment: If that doesn't help, try this: [Good Example](http://www.webinfopedia.com/multiple-file-download-by-creating-zip-file-in-PHP.html)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanYanivBenAvraham But in that two way you said the file after create save in host (like my script). In another word i am using thats ways.