# LAMP: How to create .Zip from remote URLs/files and stream it to the client on the fly

Tags: php, zip, pipe, lamp

With external services like S3 for object storage, the old problem of providing custom zip archives of stored files gets a bit more complicated. One way would be for a web server to copy all the resources to temporary local files, compile them into a .zip, then return the zip to the user, but this is slow and resource intensive.

Can this be done similarly to the [solution for local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357073/lamp-how-to-create-zip-of-large-files-for-the-user-on-the-fly-without-disk-cp)? e.g. can you `curl` the files, pipe them into `zip` in streaming mode, then out to the user on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes — you can have `zip` operate on a **set of fifos** rather than a set of files. Here’s the code:

```
$sh = 'mkfifo a.jpg b.jpg ; '.                     // 1
  'curl -s some_service.com/a.jpg > a.jpg & ' .    // 2
  'curl -s some_service.com/b.jpg > b.jpg & ' .    // 
  'zip -FI - a.jpg b.jpg | cat > out.fifo';        // 3

// Open output fifo & curl-zip task pipe
posix_mkfifo('out.fifo', 0777);                    // 4
$pipe_output = popen('cat out.fifo', 'r');         //
$pipe_curlzip = popen($sh, 'r');                   //
```

It works as follows:

1. We have two remote files: `some_service.com/a.jpg` and `some_service.com/b.jpg` – we create a fifo for each, each fifo having the name of the corresponding file as we wish it to appear in our zip file. So for `some_service.com/a.jpg`, we create a fifo called `a.jpg`.
2. Kick off two `curl` tasks to feed the remote files `a.jpg` and `b.jpg` into each’s respective fifo. These curl tasks will hang until something reads from their output fifos, so we run them in the background (`&`).
3. Start our `zip` task, giving it our two fifos as input. We `cat` its streaming output into a *third* fifo – `out.fifo` – to allow our PHP process to stream the file to the user.
4. Kick things off.

It's then just a matter of reading what comes out of `out.fifo` and sending it to the user:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Download.zip"');

while (!feof($pipe_output)) {
    echo fread($pipe_output, 128);   // Your magic number here
}
```