# How to construct a ZipArchive on the fly without using the file system

Tags: php, symfony, zip

I want to construct a zip and serve it back to the user. I currently use Symfony and so far I have the following which works well:

```
// Create zip.
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open('/tmp/foo.zip', \ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFromString("test1.txt", "test 1 content");
$zip->addFromString("test2.txt", "test 2 content");
$zip->close();

// Read zip.
$stream = fopen('/tmp/foo.zip', 'r');
$zipData = fread($stream, 1024);
fclose($stream);
unlink('/tmp/foo.zip');

// Serve zip.
$response = new Response($zipData);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=foo.zip');
return $response;
```

My problem is that I want to avoid having to use the file system (`/tmp/foo.zip`). I tried `$zip->open('php://memory', ...)` which I thought that would do the job but it didn't work (result file was always 0 bytes). Is there a way to solve this?

*Edit*: I want to be using vanilla PHP and not directly make use of commands of the underlying O/S.

Comment: Not possible with PHP streams as the ZipArchive forcibly needs a file name to create the archive. Below thread seems to do what you wish for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LAMP: How to create .Zip of large files for the user on the fly, without disk/CPU thrashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357073/lamp-how-to-create-zip-of-large-files-for-the-user-on-the-fly-without-disk-cp)

Comment: @nice_dev thanks but I want to be using vanilla PHP and not commands of the underlying O/S.

Comment: Well, I am afraid, it ain't possible then.

Comment: I don't think the feature is supported natively. There's a [third-party package](https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP).